# Are there Exchange Web Services (exchange.asmx) for Office365?

Tags: web-services, rest, office365, exchangewebservices

My company was running an internal Exchange server.  We had an internal windows service that would poll a particular mailbox to read some data and store attachments from those email messages as part of a back end process.

Last week we moved our mail service to Office365 in the cloud, and the aforementioned service has now started failing.

The current code is wired to use the old Exchange.asmx services (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53553207-ff98-4fdb-8716-4ae02fee83bf(v=exchg.140)), so essentially it's talking to https://mail.mycompany.com/ews/exchange.asmx

With Office365, I see that there are now RESTful API's and the like - https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/office-365-unified-api-overview  Are there any "legacy" API's available?  I know RESTful is the way to go, but rather than re-engineer this thing, I'm hoping I can find the .asmx equivalent today to get this up and running, since the current code uses the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices namespace.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes EWS will work fine in Exchange Online see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj162981.aspx you can just use the endpoint https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx or use Autodiscover (which will return that endpoint anyway).

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks Glen, that did the trick!